# A faster alternative for System.Drawing.Bitmap constructor

Tags: c#, performance, image-processing, bitmap, arrays

m using C# standard class `System.Drawing.Bitmap` to build images and save them to `System.IO.MemoryStream`. I have 1497600-elements byte arrays as a source. Every array represents a 960x520 pixel matrix with 3 bytes per pixel (one for each channel: R, G, B). I'm using this `Bitmap` constructor to build an image from it:

```
public Bitmap(
    int width,
    int height,
    int stride,
    PixelFormat format,
    IntPtr scan0
)
```

That's my code:

```
var arrayHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(bmpBytes, GCHandleType.Pinned);
var bmp = new Bitmap(960, 520, 960 * 3, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, arrayHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject());
bmp.Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

This is a fragment, which is executed many times a second. And `Bitmap` constructor is not so fast, nearly 14ms per call. I can't say, it's very slow, but, copying pixels array into another one by one with iterator is nearly 5 times faster, for example. As far as I know, `BMP` file is just an array of pixels with small description fragment, so, may be, the process can be accelerated?

Comment: Are you sure that it's the `new Bitmap` lines that takes so long? Are you testing in release mode?

Comment: I'm testing in debug, but both of operations: creating Bitmap and byte array copying with iterator.

Comment: Test it in release mode then come back to us

Comment: Hmm, no, profiling is tricky business.  That bitmap constructor costs about 0.2 msec.  You'll only get 14 msec when you have to pay for the cost of allocating RAM pages.  Like when you write to that MemoryStream.  But only the first time, not the second time.  Easy to see in Task Manager, add the "Page faults" counter.  Re-use buffers to avoid that cost.

Comment: Nearly 25% faster, but maybe can still be accelerated?

Comment: _Nearly 25% faster_ After changing what??

Comment: @TaW after switching to release mode.